# Gnu Emacs: send commands from other program?

Tags: emacs, gnu

Is it possible to send commands to Gnu Emacs from another program?

It would e.g. be nice if I could tell emacs go to a certain line in the current text document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, M-x `server-start` in Emacs (or put `(server-start)` in your init.el file).

Then you should be able to send Emacs commands with emacsclient - for example to go to line #10 in whatever buffer has focus:

```
emacsclient --eval "(with-current-buffer (window-buffer) (goto-line 10))"
```

(Thanks to comments below for pointing out errors! Always test )

Comment: This does not work - it's slightly more complicated, this worked in my tests: `emacsclient --eval '(with-current-buffer (window-buffer) (goto-line 12))'`

Comment: Thanks a lot, but that doesn't seem to work. Maybe I'm doing it wrong. I start `emacs --daemon`. It just says "Starting emacs daemon" in the shell output, but doesn't open an editor window (even if I provide a filename) --- is it supposed to open an emacs window at this point? Then I open an emacs with the file I want to edit (`emacs myfile`). Then I tried both the version by Tommy Jollyboat and by Tom Regner, but nothing happens (command executes without error in the shell, though). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Ah, I looked at https://wikemacs.org/wiki/Emacs_server, and you have to open the file with `emacsclient myfile`. Then the command given by Tom Regner works. But the emacs opened in the shell, how can I get an X window?

Comment: Ah, option `-c`. So to summarize: `emacs --daemon` followed by `emacsclient -c myfile` followed by `emacsclient --eval '(with-current-buffer (window-buffer) (goto-line 12))'` as suggested by Tom Regner. Perfect, thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry about the errors! I'm away from home and typed it on a phone from memory. Thanks for corrections, everyone :)

Comment: Rather than running Emacs with --daemon, just evaluating `(server-start)` (perhaps put it in your init.el) ought to make it ready for the form Tom Regner suggested.